# Remove last two characters of a string column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a column where the values are strings. I need to display those values after removing the last two characters, e.g. `199902345` should become `1999023`.

The length of the string is variable; it could be 9, 10, 11 or whatsoever characters long.

I tried looking into the `TRIM` function but apparently it can only remove the specified substring. In my case, I don't know what the substring (the last two characters) is.

What MySQL string function enables to remove/delete/trim the last two characters of a string?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? INT or VARCHAR. INT will allow faster calculations.

Comment: @Salman its VARCHAR (as we have Chars also in our implementation)

Comment: OK then `SUBSTRING` seems appropriate. For INT datatype, it was as easy as dividing by 100.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Why not use the `LEFT(string, length)` function instead of substring?

```sql
LEFT(col, char_length(col) - 2)
```

You can learn more about MySQL String functions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, I prefer this answer. I read some discussion about LEFT() being slightly more performant than SUBSTRING() but I'm not able to find a link right now.

It would be great if you could add a link to the mysql documentation for the LEFT function.

Comment: Much better solution than SUBSTRING()

Comment: If the difference is putting `, 1` in the function call, I think having a whole new function to do that is just namespace pollution.  `RIGHT` is slightly more useful in that it may save you from a `LENGTH()` calculation but still, any performance gain between these two is likely much less than the cost of calling `LENGTH()` separately.  One or two add operations per call is the only difference between `LEFT` `RIGHT` and `SUBSTRING`.  In SQL performance 2 native adds is nothing.

Comment: I had to use CHAR_LENGTH instead of LENGTH but this solution worked well.

Comment: Wait, this is an incorrect answer! It should be CHAR_LENGTH!!! I've just corrected it

Answer (score 140):

To select all characters except the last *n* from a string (or put another way, remove last *n* characters from a string); use the [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) functions together:

```
SELECT col
     , SUBSTRING(col FROM 1 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(col) - 2) AS col_trimmed -- ANSI Syntax
     , SUBSTRING(col,     1,    CHAR_LENGTH(col) - 2) AS col_trimmed -- MySQL Syntax
FROM tbl
```

To remove a specific substring from the end of string, use the [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function:

```
SELECT col
     , TRIM(TRAILING '.php' FROM col)
-- index.php becomes index
-- index.php.php becomes index (!)
-- index.txt remains index.txt
```

Comment: This Solution is very nice. But it requires to have direct access to the column. If the column is the result of some other Stringmanipulations this could be used instead:
    REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE("some_string")), 2))

Answer (score 3):

substring().

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: The length of the entries in the column is not known. I think, substring works better only for fixed length results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LENGTH(that_string)` minus the `number of characters` you want to remove in the `SUBSTRING()` select perhaps or use the `TRIM()` function.

Comment: If you can show an example of `TRIM()` working for all characters by index instead of removing all of a certain type of characters I'd be interested to see it.