# Mysql database Query check digit

Tags: mysql

I have table  grocery_items with column plu_items which has 12 digit upc code, for ex 123456789123.

How to to remove the last check digit i:e "3" in above ex. in a sql query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip last two characters of a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080662/strip-last-two-characters-of-a-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `left()`:

```
select left(plu_items, length(plu_items) - 1)
from grocery_items;
```

You should review MySQL [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html).  They are well-documented.

If you actually want to *remove* the last digit from the data, use `update`:

```
update grocery_items
    set plu_items = left(plu_items, length(plu_items) - 1);
```

Be careful, because this affects all the data.

Comment: Here (plu_times)?

Comment: Thanks its show me the result perfect.But how i can remove that last digit ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just divide by `10`

```
select cast(plu_items / 10 as unsigned) as plu_items
from grocery_items
```

Comment: Thanks,its show me the result.But how i can remove that last digit ?