# Add a '0' in beginning of all values of one column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this table here:

[image]

Inside column `[E]` I need to add a '0' for all values inside that column
like this:

[image]

How will I write the query?

Also, after that, I need to merge the columns `[E]` and `[F]` together and then replace it with column `[E]`. But I'll find that out. 
Column type is a `VARCHAR` and using SQLWorkbench

Comment: What is the data type of `E`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a simple update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET E = CONCAT('0', E);
```

*However*, if the leading zero is really just a presentation requirement, you might want to *not* do this update.  Instead, maybe create a view or just handle it in the presentation layer.

Comment: If I wanted to place a '0' at the end of the string, how would the current code be amended to its appropriate situation?

Comment: Just use `CONCAT(E, '0')`

Comment: Just added an extra zero at the end of the string, how would I then remove 1 character at the end of the string for all values?

Comment: Use `SET E = SUBSTRING(E, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(E) - 2)`

Comment: If you have spare time Tim, could you explain your latest code that you have just posted? Thanks

Comment: @Eduards Please [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080662/strip-last-two-characters-of-a-column-in-mysql).